# Форма подготовленная в Qt Designer не правильно загружается в окно

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qss

[image: фото]

Я импортировал файл с этим загрузочным экраном в **main.py**

[image: ajnj]

Отрисовал его, но вот что получается при запуске:

[image: фото]

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets    
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon 
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
################################## Тут вызовы  ui файлов

from Apex import Ui_MainWindow # Основное окно начало

from weaponsUIrepeat import Ui_other # окно Оружия
from wedomiy import Ui_MainWindow1 # окно пистолета wedomiy
from pistoll import Ui_MainWindow2 # окно пистолеты
from p2020 import Ui_MainWindow3 # окно пистолета p2020
from RE import Ui_MainWindow4 # окно пистолета RE 
from pp import Ui_MainWindow5 # окно пистолеты пулемёты 
from SMG import Ui_MainWindow6 # окно Пп сменщик 
from ISH import Ui_MainWindow7 # окно Пп ищейка
from R99 import Ui_MainWindow8 # окно Пп R99
from VOLT import Ui_MainWindow9 # окно Пп R99
from Spravka import Ui_Form #окно справки
from progress import Ui_Form1

class Apexhelper(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                          # + Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Apexhelper, self).__init__(parent) 
        self.setupUi(self)

class SplashScreen(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SplashScreen, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


    # ## Remove Title Bar
    #     self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    #     self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

class Spravka(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Spravka, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


class Wedomi(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow1):                            # + Ui_MainWindow1
    def __init__(self):
        super(Wedomi, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 

class Weapon(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_other):                                  # + Ui_other
    def __init__(self):
        super(Weapon, self).__init__()     
        self.setupUi(self)

class pistoll (QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(pistoll, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
      #  self.setStyleSheet(' .QWidget {background-image: url(5555.jpg);}')

class P2020 (QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow3):
    def __init__(self):
        super(P2020, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class RE(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow4):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RE, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class PP(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow5):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PP, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class SMG(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow6):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SMG, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class ISH(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow7):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ISH, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class R99(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow8):
    def __init__(self):
        super(R99, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class VOLT(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow9):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VOLT, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)             


# Начало основного класса 
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)      #создали центральный виджет  
        # Начало класса apexHelper
        self.apexHelper = Apexhelper(self) # экземпляр класса ApexHelper
        self.apexHelper.weapon.clicked.connect(self.gotoWeapon)
        self.apexHelper.spravka.clicked.connect(self.gotospravka)
        # конец класса apexHelper
        
        # self.test = Test() ------------------------------------------------------

        # Начало класса Weapon
        self.weapon = Weapon() # экземпляр класса Weapon
        self.weapon.back.clicked.connect(self.gotomain)
        self.weapon.pistol.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)
        self.weapon.PistolP.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса Weapon

        #начало класса Spravka
        self.spravka = Spravka() #экземпляр класса Spravka
        self.spravka.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.gotomain)
        self.spravka.vk.clicked.connect(self.on_link)
        #конец класса Spravka

        # Начало класса pistoll
        self.pist = pistoll() #экземпляр класса pistoll
        self.pist.backk.clicked.connect(self.gotoWeapon)
        # конец класса pistoll

        # начало класса R99
        self.r99 = R99()
        self.r99.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса R99

        # начало класса VOLT
        self.volt = VOLT()
        self.volt.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса VOLT


        # начало класса SMG
        self.smg = SMG()
        self.smg.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса SMG

        # начало класса ISH
        self.ish = ISH()
        self.ish.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса ISH

        # Начало класса p2020
        self.p2020 = P2020()
        self.p2020.back1.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)
        # конец класса p2020

        # Начало класса RE
        self.re = RE()
        self.re.back1.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)
        # конец класса RE

        # Начало класса Пистолеты-полемёты
        self.pp = PP() #экземпляр класса PP
        self.pp.backkk.clicked.connect(self.gotoWeapon)
        self.pp.smen.clicked.connect(self.gotosmg)
        self.pp.ihek.clicked.connect(self.gotoish)
        self.pp.R99.clicked.connect(self.gotoR99)
        self.pp.volt.clicked.connect(self.gotovolt)
        # Конец класса Пистолеты-полемёты



        # Начало класса wedomi
        self.wedomi = Wedomi() # экземпляр класса Wedomi    
        self.wedomi.backtoweapon.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)                          
        # Конец класса wedomi

        #Начало виджетов
        self.stack = QStackedWidget()      # QStackedWidget видно сразу несколько виджетов                                                  # !!!               
        self.stack.addWidget(self.apexHelper)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.weapon)    # 1   self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.wedomi) # 2 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.pist) #3 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(3) - ломается
        self.stack.addWidget(self.p2020) #4 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(4)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.re) #5 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(5)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.pp) #6 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(6)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.smg) #7 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(7)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.ish)#8 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(8)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.r99)#9 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(9)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.volt)#10 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(10)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.spravka) #11 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(11)
        
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())  
        self.gotomain()   
       

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0) #вроде можно без этого ????????????????????????????????????
        hbox.addWidget(self.stack)
    
    def nameProgramm(self, w=0):
        if w == 0:
            self.setWindowTitle('Apex Helper')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('gg.jpg'))                         
        elif w == 1:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Weapon')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('rtg.jpg'))                             
        elif w == 2:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Wedomi')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('wedomiy.png'))       
        elif w == 3:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Pistol')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('ty.jpg'))
        elif w == 4:   
            self.setWindowTitle('P2020')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('p2020.png'))
        elif w == 5:   
            self.setWindowTitle('RE-45 Auto')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('re.png'))
        elif w == 6:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Pistol-P')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('fgh.png')) 
        elif w == 7:   
            self.setWindowTitle('SMG')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('SMG.png'))
        elif w == 8:   
            self.setWindowTitle('ISH')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('ish.png'))
        elif w == 9:   
            self.setWindowTitle('R99')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('R99.png'))    
        elif w == 10:   
            self.setWindowTitle('VOLT')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Volt.png'))   
        elif w == 11:
            self.setWindowTitle('Справка')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('kisspng.jpg'))                                        

    def gotomain(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

        self.setFixedSize(400, 531)
        
    def gotoWeapon(self):  
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

        #self.resize(435, 772)
        self.setFixedSize(435, 625) # С этим разобрались
        
    def gotowedomi(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotopistol(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(3)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
        self.setFixedSize(481, 673)
    
    def gotop2020(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(4)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotoRE(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(5)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotoPP(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(6)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotosmg(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(7)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotoish(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(8)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotoR99(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(9)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotovolt(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(10)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotospravka(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(11)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
        self.setFixedSize(400, 510)

    def on_link(self):
        url = 'https://vk.com/iddota2reborn1'
        QtGui.QDesktopServices.openUrl(QtCore.QUrl(url))


if __name__ == "__main__":     
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = SplashScreen()   #Изменил было MainWindow
    #w.setFixedSize(435, 625)                                      # --- ApexHelper(), +++ MainWindow
    w.show()            
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**progress.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form1(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(680, 400)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("QFrame {\n"
"background-color: rgb(56, 58, 89);\n"
"color: rgb(220, 220, 220);\n"
"border-radius: 10px\n"
"\n"
"}")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 651, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(254, 121, 199);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.frame)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 278, 581, 21))
        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar {\n"
"   \n"
" background-color: rgb(98, 114, 164);\n"
" color: rgb(200, 200, 200);\n"
" border-style:  none;\n"
" border-radius: 10px;\n"
"text-align: center\n"
"}\n"
"QProgressBar::chunk{\n"
"  border-radius: 10 px;\n"
"  background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0.545, x2:1, y2:0.54, stop:0 rgba(254, 121, 199, 255), stop:1 rgba(170, 85, 255, 255));\n"
"}")
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(242, 170, 201, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(98, 114, 164);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(298, 300, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(98, 114, 164);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 350, 181, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(98, 114, 164);")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "<strong>Apex</strong>Helper"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "<strong>Your Helper</strong> in game"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>loading...</p></body></html>"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "<strong>Created</strong>: Nanoxia"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form1()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dDqFdUJ-J1ggRFX5OLuaX43_ObylRoRV?usp=sharing

вот ссылка на все файлы

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick Добавил два файла. Снизу есть ссылка на все файлы

Comment: Я только что поставил код вандерсона и всё заработало.. Почему же мой код не хочет работать

Comment: @S.Nick, всё я решил проблему :) Почему когда я создал Widget в qt-desinger, то не работало, а как только создал mainwindow, то всё заработало. Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрытая ошибка. Когда вы создавали форму вы использовали базовый класс `QWidget`, а пытаетесь загрузить форму в виджет, который наследуется от `QMainWindow` - это не правильно.

Замените

```
class SplashScreen(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form1):
```

на

```
class SplashScreen(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form1):
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets    
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon 
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

#from progress import Ui_Form1
class Ui_Form1(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(680, 400)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("QFrame {\n"
"background-color: rgb(56, 58, 89);\n"
"color: rgb(220, 220, 220);\n"
"border-radius: 10px\n"
"\n"
"}")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 651, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(254, 121, 199);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.frame)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 278, 581, 21))
        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar {\n"
"    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(98, 114, 164);\n"
"    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);\n"
"    border-style: none;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"}\n"
"QProgressBar::chunk{\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0.511364, x2:1, y2:0.523, stop:0 rgba(254, 121, 199, 255), stop:1 rgba(170, 85, 255, 255));\n"
"}")
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(242, 170, 201, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(98, 114, 164);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(298, 300, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(98, 114, 164);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 350, 181, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(98, 114, 164);")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "<strong>Apex</strong>Helper"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "<strong>Your Helper</strong> in game"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>loading...</p></body></html>"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "<strong>Created</strong>: Nanoxia"))


#class SplashScreen(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form1):
class SplashScreen(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SplashScreen, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":     
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = SplashScreen()   #Изменил было MainWindow
    #w.setFixedSize(435, 625)           # --- ApexHelper(), +++ MainWindow
    w.show()            
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался, но я до сих пор не пойму, почему у меня не закругляется progress bar, конкретно в qt-designer.... Вроде всё делаю, как всегда, но не идёт

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер я же вам подправил. Возьмите стили с моего примера.

Comment: Взять-возьму. Но хочу понять, Посижу подумаю. А пока возникла новая ошибка)

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер просто скопируйте, вы где-то при наборе допускаете ошибки.